# How to convert String from json to float array?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

in my json data i have data in Array as string e.g:

```
//
"values": "{{0, 25}, {96.86, 184}}",
"matrix": "[1, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0]",
//
```

now, I getting the data as String. how can i convert the data to float[]?

Comment: do you want to convert this values {{0, 25}, {96.86, 184}}?

Comment: yes please......

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse like this,

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject("[your Json String]");

    String value = object.optString("values");

    String floatStr = value.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");

    String[] valuesArr = floatStr.split(",");

    float[] floatArr = new float[valuesArr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < valuesArr.length; i++) {
        String floatString = valuesArr[i];

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(floatStr) || TextUtils.isEmpty(floatStr.trim())) {
            floatArr[i] = 0.0f;
            continue;
        }

        floatArr[i] = Float.parseFloat(floatString.trim());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < floatArr.length; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "value : at " + i + " is " + floatArr[i]);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your json data and use

```
Float.parseFloat(your_float_value_in_string)
```

Comment: But what about if the float is in array?

Answer (score 0):

İf I dont understand wrong Do it first :Sprit your character with String tokenizer then every String seems like number Last thing you have to do take to part of String and put in float Array